# The best extension method overload requires a receiver of type List

Tags: c#, .net-core

the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type List
i am facing this problem:

> list jvdem does not contain the defination for ToModelListJVDET and the best extension overload method modelhelper.ToModelListJVDET(List) requires a receiver of type list

so please check my code and guide me how can i solve this problem

This is my code:

```cs
// Controller

public IActionResult Index() {
    List<JVDM> jVDMs = new LocationHandler().GetjVDM().ToModelListJVDET();

    return View(jVDMs);
}

// ModelHelper class

public static List<JVDetModel> ToModelListJVDET(this List<JVDetModel> entityJVDetModels) {
    List<JVDetModel> jVDetModel = new List<JVDetModel>();

    foreach (var i in entityJVDetModels) {
        jVDetModel.Add(i);
    }

    jVDetModel.TrimExcess();
    return jVDetModel;
}


// Location Handler

public List<JVDM> GetjVDM() {
    using (myDBContext context = new myDBContext()) {
        return (from c in context.JVDetTable select c).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello Ammar, welcome to SO. your question is not clear at all. what is the exact problem?! are you facing any special error?!

Comment: _GetjVDM().ToModelListJVDET()_ - well, `GetjVDM` returns `List<JVDM>` and `ToModelListJVDET` expects to be passed a `List<JVDetModel>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
GetjVDM().ToModelListJVDET();
```

`GetjVDM()` returns `List<JVDM>` while `ToModelListJVDET` expects `List<JVDetModel> entityJVDetModels`

You can do the following:

1. **Change the expectation of `ToModelListJVDET` to `List<JDVM>`**

```
public static List<JVDetModel> ToModelListJVDET(this List<JDVM> JDVMs) {
    List<JVDetModel> jVDetModel = new List<JVDetModel>();

    foreach (var i in JDVMs) {
        jVDetModel.Add(
            // Create the new model
            new JVDetModel() {
                 Propery1 = i.Property1
                 // etc in mapping
            }
        );
    }

    jVDetModel.TrimExcess();
    return jVDetModel;
}
```

2. **Another thing you could to is to select the JVDetModel from your linq and effectively return `List<JVDetModel>` from `GetjVDM`**

```
public List<JVDetModel> GetjVDM() {
    using (myDBContext context = new myDBContext()) {
        return (from c in context.JVDetTable select new JVDetModel {/* Create the model here*/}).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You #Athanasios Kataras

Answer (score 1):

The method `GetjVDM()` returns a `List<JDVM>` and your extension method `ToModelListJVDET` is extend `List<JVDetModel>`.

So if you want to call `ToModlListJVDET` you need to extend `List<JDVM>`, or instead return a `List<JVDetModel>` from `GetjVDM()`.